# do while loop that ends when n doesnt equal 1 or 22

Tags: c++

this is my first time posting so I hope that I am doing this right. The instructions for this assignment are

Write a C++ program that implements the following algorithm:

1. input n
2. print n
3. if n = 1 then stop
4. if n is odd then n <-- 3n+1
5. else n <-- n/2
6. goto step 2

Example: given the input 22, the following sequence of numbers will be printed:

22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1

do not use break to exit a loop

so far I have this code written out

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int n = 0;
    int set1 = 1;
    int set22 = 22;
    string outPut;

    outPut = "22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1";

    //input phase
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> n;

    //processing phase
    if (n == 1)
    {

    }
    else if (n != 22)
    {
        do
        {
            if (n % 2 != 0)
            {
                n = (3 * n) + 1;
            }
            else if (n % 2 == 0)
            {
               n = (n / 2);
            }
            cout << n << endl;
        } while (n != set1 || n != set22);
    }

    //if statement for output
    if (n == 22)
    {
        cout << outPut << endl;
    }
}
```

but it seems that it is still not exiting the while loop once getting 1 or 22. Any ideas or help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Not directly related, but why do you have this special case for `n=22`? It would just follow the algorithm and go to one on its own, printing the same result as you do manually.

Comment: Indenting could be improved. I'd take off points if you turned this in.

Comment: Odds are that you are *not* required to treat 22 as a special case. I think they show its output in the problem statement just as an *example* of a correct computation.

Comment: @nicomp how would u indent this differently? My teacher said to use the astyle command to fix formatting but it just looks terrible

Comment: When you open a curly brace, indent, when you close a curly brace, outdent (yes, that's a word). Your last brace at the bottom should be in the left-most column. That's pretty standard.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question being asked. The output for n=22 is just an example of what your code should produce if you input 22, a way for you to test if your algorithm is working correctly. Read the pseudo-code provided carefully. Your code should ask for an input, assign that input to `n`, then within a while loop `cout<<n` and then check if   `n` is odd or even and update the value of `n` according to the pseudocode (3n+1
 if odd, n/2 otherwise). The loop should terminate if `n` is updated to have the value 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n != set1 || n != set22` will be always true because `set1` and `set22` have different values and `n` cannot be equal to both of them at once.

Use `n != set1 && n != set22` instead of that.

Comment: but the thing is that if either n equals 1 or 22 then I need it to stop. not both

Comment: @RyanBlaise To stop, the condition must become false. Then you may like `!(n == set1 || n == set22)`